# Dilated LSTM vs LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language-processing, classification

I'm currently reading a paper for a literature review related to NLP and its research employs a dilated LSTM model.

What is the difference between this and a regular LSTM, or more specifically what does the dilation do?

I read a couple of papers explaining dilated RNN but it doesn't resonate with me. (this one in particular: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/32bb90e8976aab5298d5da10fe66f21d-Paper.pdf )